# DJANGO celery task is executed from shell but it's not executed from view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-celery

I am trying to create some asynchronous tasks with celery in my django application

settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'django://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'provcon.settings')

app = Celery('provcon')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

project __init__py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from celery import task
from .models import Proc_Carga
@task()
def carga_ftp():
    tabla = Proc_Carga()
    sp = tabla.carga()

    return None
```

I call the asysnchronous tasks from my view like this:

```
from .tasks import carga_ftp

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def archivoview(request):
    usuario= request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProcFTPForm(usuario,request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          proc = Lista_Final()
          lista = proc.archivos()
          # call asynchronous task 
          carga_ftp.delay()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/resumen/')
    else:
      form = ProcFTPForm(usuario)
    return render_to_response('archivo.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I run the task from the python manage.py shell. The worker is executed and create the database objects without any problem

but when I try to execute the task from the view, doesn't work is not executed

Any idea why the task run from the manage.py shell but not from the views

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if redis is running

```
$redis-cli ping
```

Check if the celery worker is running in the django admin interface

If not running execute this command

```
celery -A provcon worker -l info
```

Test your task from your django application

If works run the celery worker in background like a [daemon](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with me.
Task is working in python shell but it is not working in Django views.

I followed this 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

I was missing namespace in app.config_from_object, after adding namespace='CELERY', It is working fine.

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```